# jQuery/CSS animation - original state flickering over transitioned state

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, flicker

I'm having a problem with my animations flickering upon completion. I'm using a mix of jQuery and CSS to slide divs, and my problem seems unique to me. The exact problem consists of sliding a 200% width div 50% left and right, using  `$("element").css("transform","translate(-50%,0px)");` in jQuery and `transition:all 0.43s ease-in-out;` in the CSS (all proper browser prefixes are iterated as necessary).

The animation takes place flawlessly until the point of completion, and then for a split second it flashes the original state, and then back to the transitioned state. Except for the flicker of the original state instead of the transitioned state for about 0.001 seconds, that code works exactly as planned.

An especially odd side-occurrence is that I have (custom JS, not actual) dropdowns in both states, which jQuery closes before the sliding animation takes place, but when the flicker takes place, it shows the dropdown still expanded. When sliding back, the dropdown is closed as it should be. These previously worked together flawlessly, and I haven't touched either piece of code today.

It's literally like it's taking a screenshot of what the page state was before the animation, doing exactly what I want it to do, and then flashing the screenshot of the before state to taunt me deliberately.

I can't post a JSfiddle unfortunately, because I can't reproduce the problem in isolation, and I'm quite certain that my employer would not like me to post the entire code here. I'm sorry I can't provide more. Thanks for any help you can give.

> *(To any wondering, I've looked at quite a few other examples where
>   `overflow:hidden` on the parent element will stop certain animations
>   from flickering and jumping to their final positions without animating
>   the last bit. But that's not what's happening here. I have had that
>   problem before myself, and this is not it).*

****Update:** Upon further examination, this problem only takes place in Chrome, not in Safari or Firefox. I updated Chrome to 18.0.1025.142 today, and that may be the problem.

Comment: Without code, it's hard to help. Javascript is clientside anyway so unless it's an intranet there's no difference to posting it here vs view-source. Have you tried removing the CSS easing and trying to implement it all via jQuery?

Comment: **Another Update:** More weird stuff is happening in Chrome today, related to jQuery and CSS animations, involving display errors where gradient bars which exist nowhere in the code begin appearing upon transition trigger, and display across the entire screen. There are both vertical and horizontal bars. It's not webkit, it's Chrome itself; tested in Safari everything works fine. Same with Firefox, etc. It appears Chrome's got an animation bug, but I'm not sure how to get rid of it. And thanks, Alex, but no, there is no difference when switching to pure jQuery.

Comment: Hmph. I was able to fix all of those problems somehow. And they were all completely different solutions than I thought they'd be. Actually, yes @Alex, I thought I'd switched to jQuery entirely, but it turns out that I edited the wrong transition on the page, and I was still seeing the problems on the one with the CSS implementation. Once I figured that out and switched the *problematic one* to jQuery only, it works fine now in Chrome. So I'm somewhat at a loss: Was the CSS code I had incorrect? Does the new version of Chrome have a bug relating to jQuery/Javascript/CSS? I still have no idea.

Comment: Just to play through how I would test a few things myself - can you try setting the time to 1s instead of 0.43s, and try it without the easing as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex. At this point, as long as it works *at all*, I'm happy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to one of my problems had to do with browser-supplied gradients on un-styled form objects propagating for the full width and height of the page (even when on a lower z-index than other elements they were hidden behind) due to a "variable not found" error in my JavaScript. Once I defined the Javascript variable before calling it with jQuery, the strange gradients disappeared. I can only chalk up the weird behavior to improper parsing based on not being able to find the variable it wanted. Even though it seemed completely unrelated, it was the right solution.